# KML to control Optional Features (such as "Tour Guide")

Tags: c#, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I'm new to KML programming but have gotten most of what I need to do working, which is multiple map overlays.

One thing I want to control but haven't found a way to do so are the options you can turn on/off via "View" on the GoogleEarth.exe menu.

For instance, if I run Google Earth stand alone, turn on "Tour Guide" (View > Tour Guide), then terminate Google Earth, when I start up my application that interacts with Google Earth, the Tour Guide photo strip is on.  If I exit my app, re-run Google Earth, turn off the Tour Guide, and exit, then the next time I start my app and it starts Google Earth the Tour Guide is off.

Are there KML commands to control this ("Tour Guide") and other optional features?  I'd like to do this inside my app rather than forcing the user to manually configure the settings the way my application wants them.

By the way, I'm coding in C# in .NET Framework 4, using GoogleEarth version 7.0.2.8415, and running on Windows/XP and above.

Thanks for any help/guidance you can supply!

- john

Comment: For what it's worth, after further digging, I did find that if I set the following REGEDIT key to "false", the Tour Guide strip is off when I fire up GoogleEarth: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Googl‌​e Earth Plus\TourGuide\Filmstrip\Enable**. I'm hopeful there's an easier way via KML to do this.

Comment: Are you using the Google Earth COM api, or the JavaScript Plugin api? It isn't clear...

Comment: @Fraser -- COM API.  Apologies for the latent response....

Comment: Ah, you should [be aware that it has been depreciated](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/sunset-for-google-earth-com-api.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Earth provides additional elements in it's extended KML namespace to achieve things like the tours (using the gx: prefix for those XML elements as you describe / have used above). In all cases these extended elements tell Google Earth how to interact with the various geographical elements within the KML, and none define the behaviour of the Google Earth application and plugin in anyway.

So, short answer is out of the box Google Earth and KML cannot achieve your desired behaviour.

**EDIT** Here is the relevant link to controlling the tour if you are using the Google Earth Plugin in you app: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_tour_player

Comment: Okay, cool, thanks, Matthew.  I've been able to work around this by setting keys in the registry. This is kind of a kludge and may end up version dependent, but it's the only workaround I've figured out. FWIW, the setting is in HKEy CurrentUser Software\Google\Google Earth Plus\TourGuide\Filmstrip

Comment: Note that my 'no' is limited to accomplishing this in KML. There are other ways to control behaviour in Google Earth - specifically if your plan is to use the API and not the application (read the JavaScript API for details on what can/cannot be done). I don't have any experience trying to customize with the Google Earth Application itself so I won't comment yes/no on it.  Also - it's good karma to mark a question that answered yours as the correct answer (and maybe up-vote it while at it :).

Comment: sorry for the latent +1  <hangsHeadInNubieShame>